# detecting end of http header with \r\n\r\n

Tags: c, http

Using recv I want to get the http header so I can parse for a content length. However I'm having trouble detecting the line break. Or actually do I even have to detect line break or will the first time I read into the buffer always be the complete header (assuming I have a long enough buffer).

This is written in C.

edit: looking at some of the related questions one of the things I am worried about is
"...the "\r\n" of the header break might be pulled into your buffer by two different calls to recv() which would prevent your code from recognizing the header break."

Comment: Check for "\r\n\r\n" if not try reading again with a timeout. It's possible that you may not read all the content at once.

Comment: right i wanted to do this and then use regex to find the line break but actually it's not included in the library I'm given access to.

Comment: You don't need a regex you just need to compare the last 4 characters of the string with "\r\n\r\n" and check for equality.

Comment: What if the last 4 aren't the line breaks. What if the line breaks are in the middle of the message I just received. Or does that never happen and I can always assume that line breaks are at the end of the message (I think not since I experimented with a large buffer that read the first 10000 bytes of the message and it cut off in the middle of body)

Comment: It should be at the end of the message, they shouldn't be somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Julian they are indeed somewhere in the middle. you wrote that your second step would be to read the content-length field so you are also considering http-posts, and in posts recv will not pause after the \r\n\r\n, so you are right in assuming that they might be anywhere.

Comment: not worth making a whole answer, but strstr with "\r\n\r\n" as the needle and the header string as the haystack then +=4 to the return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call recv() repeatedly and each time it gives you `x` bytes you increase the buffer-pointer you give to it by `x` bytes (and decrease the cb it is allowed to write also by `x` bytes). You do this until your buffer either contains a `\r\n\r\n` or is completely full, in which case you just close the socket and ignore the malicious client from then on. Buffer-size should be about 3000 bytes.

**But**: this ignores the general problem that your server seems to be a polling-server. If you have some experience you should try to make an epoll-server instead.

Comment: I was about to +1 up until the advice about epoll. epoll is non-standard, non-portable, and unless you're dealing with thousands of simultaneous long-lived connections (rather than a few long-lived connections or tons of transient ones), much slower than the portable poll. One should never consider using epoll unless measurement has already shown there's a performance problem it could solve.

Comment: With 'an epoll-server' i meant async in general; all major OS's have something similar now. There are many denial of service vectors possibile if you use polling. epoll/async is the way to go.

Comment: OK, it sounds like you're sufficiently mixing up terminology that this conversation is going to be difficult to have, so suffice it to say I think OP should just listen to somebody who's going to explain things more clearly...

Comment: If you're equating asynchronous (normally select/poll-based) state-machine-style event loops with the Linux-specific epoll, and using the term "poll" to refer to synchronous IO, it's going to be really confusing to somebody who's not already familiar with these concepts...

Comment: The select and poll functions specified by the POSIX standard are synchronous. Depending upon the timeval provided, they also might be non-blocking. Asynchronous socket calls use callback functions or signal handlers to inform the program that socket operations have been completed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem of identifying "\r\n\r\n" across packet boundaries, you have the problem of identifying "Content-Length: xxxx\r\n" across packet boundaries. I suggest recieving and parsing one byte at a time. When you get a recv() of '\r' followed by a recv() of '\n', followed by a recv() of '\r' followed by a recv() of '\n', you can be sure the header has ended. Once you've grasped this, adapt your solution to recieve and parse n bytes at a time where n is a preprocessor definition defined to 1 initially, and change n.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did something like this:

```
while ( recv... > 0 ) {
     if rnrn is inside the buffer using strstr
         look for content length, output error if content length doesn't exist
     else
         keep on reading into the buffer
}
```

and then once the header is found I keep on reading for the message body.

anyway thanks guys, ended up doing a really inefficient way to get my answer but what must be done is done.

Comment: So **almost** what i suggested in my first paragraph. Could you accept my answer? Also: you really **shouldn't use strstr** to find the \r\n\r\n because it will run off the end of the buffer if the (malicious) client did not send a \r\n\r\n at all.

Comment: controlled environment, whatever code works works. I've accepted your answer.