# End of HTTP header

Tags: java, sockets, http, network-programming, theory

I'm trying to build a program which will identify the end of a header. Now I am aware of that http headers end with an empty line as said in [Detect end of http get request header (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928209/detect-end-of-http-get-request-header-java), however, to my understanding that is not always the case.

E.g. in multipart you have a content-type with a boundary, and in that boundary there is an empty space, example

```
Reading line: POST /hello:hello HTTP/1.1
Reading line: bla: bla
Reading line: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------276559868742390689469124
Reading line: cache-control: no-cache
Reading line: Postman-Token: be8db757-81f4-49db-9187-30d66d0dd3d5
Reading line: User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.5
Reading line: Accept: */*
Reading line: Host: localhost:8080
Reading line: accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Reading line: content-length: 498
Reading line: Connection: keep-alive
Reading line: 
Reading line: ----------------------------276559868742390689469124
Reading line: Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="TimeComplexity.txt"
Reading line: Content-Type: text/plain
```

so obviously looking for an empty space does not seem to work every time. What I have noticed though is that the Content-Type followed by a space always seems to be the end of the HTTP header, is that correct? and if not, what other solutions are there? except for extracting the content-length and extract the content before the header, it seems.. slow. Could also mention that I'm trying to parse the message in java, but I wouldn't mind examples in other languages if you are pasting any code, however, I seek to understand it theoretically, I believe I can manage the rest.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*http headers end with an empty line ... that is not always the case*" Wrong. Headers ALWAYS end with an empty line. "*looking for an empty space does not seem to work every time*" Correct, because that is not how spaces are used in HTTP headers. "*the Content-Type followed by a space always seems to be the end of the HTTP header, is that correct?*" No. The `boundary` following the `Content-Type` is **part of** that same header. It is an attribute of that header. A header ends with CRLF, its attributes (if any) are separated by `;`. Whitepace between syntax elements of a header is optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP headers may be in any order. Each header ends with CRLF, and after the last header there is a single CRLF creating an empty line. That signals that there are no more headers. The rest is the HTTP message body. See [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) for the HTTP protocol spec.

Your last HTTP header is the `Connection` header. The following body data (498 bytes in size) is MIME data in `multipart/form-data` format. MIME looks similar to HTTP, in that it also has headers and body separated by an empty line. But MIME also has boundaries separating different sections of MIME data, and each section has its own headers and body. See RFCs [2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) - [2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047), [7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) and other MIME related RFCs.

Comment: But how can that be? The three last rows are not a part of the original file

Comment: The file is not transmitted as is, but encoded as multipart/form-data (as you can see in the content type), see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578. HTTP 1.1 is a text-based protocol, so the message body is typically coded in some way.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that one should treat multipart/form-data differently in parsing? Or should the decoding be a part of the receivers/clients responsibility?

Comment: If you mean different from plain text, then yes. If you are writing a new general purpose HTTP client it is your responsibility to decode the body, most other clients can do that and you need the boundary from the header in order to parse the body. If you have a very specialized use you may get by without parsing.

Comment: Actually working on writing a socket version of servlets to understand streams and http better. Thanks a lot ewramner, swift and clean answers

Comment: @ewramner "*HTTP 1.1 is a text-based protocol*" - no, it's not. It has textual elements (request/status lines, headers, etc) but is not itself a textual protocol (and there is even work in progress to turn HTTP headers into binary data for better machine processing). The HTTP body is arbitrary data, it is up to the sender to decide how it is encoded (if at all) and the receiver to decode the body based on the headers. `multipart/form-data` is one possible encoding of body data, but it doesn't effect HTTP itself. HTTP is just the transport, MIME is the encoding of the data being transported.

Comment: @Kavzor you need an HTTP engine to process the transport of arbitrary data. You need a MIME engine to process MIME data being transported. You need a text parser to process text being transported. An image parser to process images being transported. And so on. Writing an HTTP client is a LOT of work with a LOT of different pieces working together.

Comment: @RemyLebeau there was a reason I wrote HTTP 1.1 and not just HTTP, the binary headers are in 2.0. Let's not split hairs. I would still describe HTTP 1.1 as text-based even though the body can be binary, but the important point was that the body may need to be processed differently based on content type.